strftime() on Mac returns local timezone for UTC time
I have this code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
    
int main() {
    char            timestr[10];
    struct timespec ts;
    char            tmz[6];
    struct tm       tm, *tmp = &tm;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
    gmtime_r(&ts.tv_sec, tmp);
    strftime(tmz, 6, "%z", tmp);
    snprintf(timestr, 7, "%s", tmz);
    printf("Time: %s", timestr);

    return 0;
}

This works fine on debian but gives invalid timezone on Mac. I have IST timezone on both Debian and Mac.
My understanding is that gmtime_r populates struct tm with time values without any timezone adjustments, basically UTC. Then strftime should give +0000 on both Debian and Mac
But this gives +0000 on Debian and +0530 on Mac. So I have the entire time string in UTC but the timezone information is IST on Mac
I checked the timezone offset field set by gmtime_r in tmp pointer
long tm_gmtoff; /* offset from UTC in seconds */

It was correctly set as 0, but strftime still considers local timezone while doing the calculations
Any suggestions what could be the issue here ?

Indeed gmtime_r provides a non-localized UTC time structure, reading it with strftime gives you the offset.  According to Apple:

strftime() function uses the current locale
cf. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/strftime.3.html


The function gmtime() also converts the time value, but makes no time
zone adjustment.
cf. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/gmtime_r.3.html


I understand strftime gives the offset. But it should get the offset from the time struct populated by gmtime_r, right ? And that offset is 0. Linux man page also says offset from UTC and since the time is in UTC, it correctly shows +0000 on Linux. This behavior on Mac basically shows wrong time from the time struct

The offset is in the Locale that is picked up by strftime.

That doesn't make sense. If it picks offset from Locale, why not convert the time in local timezone. Showing UTC time with IST timezone is invalid
